# TOpenDialog And Spaces

Tags: delphi, directory, spaces, lazarus

I have a project on Lazarus that I want to compile a source using gcc, for this I have a `TOpenDialog` called `OpenDialog1` and a `TProcess` called `AProcess`.

I call gcc with this code:

```
procedure TFormMain.btCompileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AProcess := TProcess.Create(nil);
    try
      AProcess.CommandLine := 'gcc.exe ' + OpenDialog1.FileName;
      AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poWaitOnExit, poUsePipes];
      AProcess.Execute;
      OutputMemo.Lines.BeginUpdate;
      OutputMemo.Lines.Clear;
      OutputMemo.Lines.LoadFromStream(AProcess.Output);
      OutputMemo.Lines.EndUpdate;
    finally
      AProcess.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

It compiles ok(the project on Lazzarus), but when I was testing it, by trying to compile the source test.c, that is located at `C:\Documents and Settings\Nathan Campos\Desktop`, I got this on `OutputMemo`:

> 'C:\Documents': No such file or directory

Then, `OpenDialog1` isn't getting the full path with the spaces, or gcc can't locate it on the folder with spaces.

Any suggestion to help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be in quotes so spaces won't trip it up.  So like this:

```
AProcess.CommandLine := 'gcc.exe "' + OpenDialog1.FileName + '"';
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've forgot about this, sorry to make you loose your time **:(**